# Finding any words in a string with its indexes

Tags: c#, algorithm, cpu-word

Let's say that I have string:

`-dog--cat--d--`

I would like to find all words from that string, and length should be greater than 1.

But what is more, I would like to know first and last index of each of the words.

How could I do that?

I was thinking about creating struct. It could store some data(index start and stop, words, length, etc.)

But I really do not know how to find out any way to get that words.

So far I only created array storing valuese 0 and 1 (if element is '-' then 0 else 1).
Can anybody help me? :)

Comment: How do you define "word"? A sequence of 2 or more Unicode letters?

Comment: A [suffix tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree) meets your requirements as I understand them, which may differ from what you meant.

Comment: @MarkByers, I define sequence Unicode letters between "-" eg. `"-dog-" => dog`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the regular expression `@"\p{L}{2,}"` to find 2 or more consecutive letters:

```
foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(s, @"\p{L}{2,}")) {
    // match.Index, match.Value, etc..
}
```

Comment: Change it to `@"\p{L}{1,}"` to get `d` to show up as well or just `@"\w+"` to select the words

Answer (score -1):

You would probably be best using **Regular Expressions** to filter out any non-letters and return an array of words

```
      String sourcestring = "-dog--cat--d--";
      Regex re = new Regex(@"\w+");
      MatchCollection mc = re.Matches(sourcestring);
      int mIdx=0;
      foreach (Match m in mc)
       {
        for (int gIdx = 0; gIdx < m.Groups.Count; gIdx++)
          {
            Console.WriteLine("[{0}][{1}] = {2}", mIdx, re.GetGroupNames()[gIdx], m.Groups[gIdx].Value);
          }
        mIdx++;
      }
```

Comment: `I would like to know first and last index of each of the words`

Comment: @L.B thanks for the downvote considering you can use The `System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match` Class to filter the words and get information like the index...